# Move bugs with history and attachments to a new project

Tags: import, export, tfs-2015

We have 2 projects in TFS 2015 that we want to merge, both are in the same project collection.

I would like to export the bugs from project B with history and attachments and import them into Project A.

I would also like to export the Test plans with Outcomes from Project B into Project A. I'm thinking the Bugs may be easier than Test Plans and results.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2015, to import work item **without** history, you can create query and export and import via Excel. See [Migrating TFS Work Items from one project to another using Excel](https://everythingabouttfs.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/migrating-tfs-work-items-from-one-project-to-another-using-excel/).

To migrate Work Item Comments, Links and Attachments you can reference [**this**](https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/bulk-migrate-work-item-comments-links-and-attachments) article.

If you want to export and import work item with history you may have to use TFS API.

Follow below steps:

- Get the Work Item Details Programmatically using TFS API
- Get the Work Item Revision ‘History’ Programmatically using TFS API

Reference below articles on using the TFS API:

- [TFS SDK: Work Item History Visualizer using TFS API](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx)
- [TFS API : TFS Work Item All Changes History](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1117462/TFS-API-TFS-Work-Item-All-Changes-History)

Another workaround is upgrading to TFS 2017 or later version, then you can [Copy or clone a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=browser#copy-or-clone-a-work-item) from one project to another with the history,links and attachments etc.

Comment: @Pat Delaney Have you resolved the issue? any update?