# How to migrate 2 team collections from tfs to one organization in azure devops services?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, ado, data-migration

From what I’ve read that for each collection will be migrating to one organization. Is there any suggestion or other way to migrate to solve this issue?

Comment: Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

By default we cannot achieve that by the official migration tool. Since each collection maps to one database in Azure DevOps Server, and the migration
process works by importing an entire collection. So, each collection will be migrating to one organization separately.

As a workaround, you can try to create new projects in the migrated organization, then manually migrate the projects, of course it will has some limits.

- For the sources,you can import the repository directly, please see
  [Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops) for details.
- For work items you can use the third-party tools or extensions or
  Microsoft Excel to do that, however the history will be missed. You can reference this thread: [Move bugs with history and attachments to a new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044144/move-bugs-with-history-and-attachments-to-a-new-project/51056408#51056408)

Comment: @NayliFatini Have you resolved the issue by the suggestions? Any update here?